# How to add a button in any expected place by using appendChild() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, appendchild

I want to add a button in my web page when a certain event is occurred  by using javaScript. I searched online much and try to solve this problem by using appendChild() function.

My code is like this :

```
var btn = document.createElement(‘button’);
btn.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Here I am facing two problems

1. My button is added but in a certain corner of my html page and
2. I can’t add style to this new created button without providing css to other buttons.

So how can I add this button in a certain positon and add css to this button

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your first problem is you added the button after body. So that your button is appeared in a certain corner of your html page.
   To solve this problem you may add this after an id containing div. And this div  must be in your expected location.
   Make a div which id is myButton in your expected location

   id="addButton"

Then append your button after this id like this

```
document.getElementById("addButton").appendChild(newButton);
```

2. To provide CSS to this new created button your CSS code will be like this

   ```
   #addButton button {
           display: block;
           background: green;
           padding: 10px;
           color: #ffffff;
       }
   ```

To provide the hover effect your code will be

```
   #addButton button:hover {
            background: red;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Append it to the document instead of a button..

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.innerText="button";
   btn.style.background="red";
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```